# Regex to validate font names

Tags: php, css, regex, validation, sql-injection

```
/((([\w -]+)|("[\w -]+"))( *, *)?)+/
```

http://refiddle.com/18ql

I'm trying to use a **PHP regex** to sanitize a user input for a **list of fonts**. The above one seems to work nicely, but also feels a bit long and redundant, having two `[\w -]*`s, and allowing a trailing comma, and possibly stuff I can't see. **Can this be more efficient (smaller, less redundant, more secure)?**

### Examples

The regex should match these:

> ```
> Roboto
> "Roboto"
> "Roboto Condensed"
> Roboto Condensed
> Roboto Condensed, Roboto
> "Roboto Condensed", Roboto
> Roboto Condensed, "Roboto"
> "Roboto Condensed", "Roboto", sans-serif
> ```

or any string that matches [the W3C specification for a CSS `font-family` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family-prop)

It must be able to match these, but not any preceding (e.g. `/*`) or succeeding (e.g. `; DROP TABLE foo`) string that might cause errors and open up exploits. So, it should match the font-family list (bold) in the following example, but not the surrounding potentially malicious characters.

> `/*`**`"Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", sans-serif`**`; DROP TABLE foo --`

Similarly, I want it to also remove strings that someone might not know would produce broken code:

> `font-family:`**`"Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", sans-serif`**`; /* My fonts */`

### My input-handling function:

```php
$userFontName = sanitizeFontName($_GET['font'])


function sanitizeFontName($fontName)
{
    $match = null;
    preg_match('/((([\w -]+)|("[\w -]+"))( *, *)?)+/', $fontName, $match); // Only get a W3C font list. Proven here: http://refiddle.com/18ql
    return $match[0]; // only one
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28b3d66469badff5d37dcc55c588871be9962cad)

Comment: Is it really necessary to filter out SQL injection attempts via regex?  If the user is intentionally trying to break the system, they deserve to end up with invalid CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon yes, because I'm not as clever as a good hacker, who might be able to figure out code injection I don't know and use it to do things to the server. I'm not a security professional, I just know I have to sanitize user input to guarantee it's only what I want, and nothing else.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for user input to do malicious things with text input unless you're running eval on it (which is bad and you shouldn't do) or you fail to insert it into the database correctly (in which case, [Bobby Tables is here to help](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)).  The only other "bad" thing a user could really do is XSS injections, but those shouldn't be possible from CSS.

Comment: The regexp is far from matching the W3C definition of allowed font names. It allows any Unicode characters, though some characters need to be escaped using CSS escape notation and some imply a need for quotation marks around the name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach is completely wrong.

### There is a difference between *escaping* and *validation*

**Validation** is the act of making sure a piece of input conforms to certain rules (be it logical, or business rules). It ***should not be used for security***. You can't catch all possible edge cases with a blacklist, don't try.

**Escaping** (or **Sanitization**) is the act of escaping characters with special meaning and replacing them with another character or a string that will have the meaning of the literal character in **the target context** (for example, replacing `<` with `&lt;` in HTML). Escaping can and should be used for making sure nothing with special meaning enters the target context (HTML, MySQL query, JavaScript, etc).

---

In your case, the context is a MySQL query, you're trying to prevent SQL injection. The solution to SQL injection is *not* validation. It's **prepared statements**. So:

```
$pdo = //Instantiate PDO connection.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO fonts(id) VALUES (:id)");
$stmt->bindValue(":id", "1; DROP TABLE fonts -- "); //Unsafe input
$stmt->execute(); //Will not drop the table. No results will be returned.
```

With an insert, the entire string `1; DROP TABLE fonts --` will be inserted.

Sometime in the future (when you try to *fetch* the font from the database), and before you **output it into CSS**, you'll want to escape the string **for this new context**. CSS escaping is something that hasn't a native PHP API, but there are probably libraries around.

Comment: I'd also like to address them putting in a wrong, but not malicious string, like in my example with `font-family:"Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", sans-serif; /* My fonts */`

Comment: That should be done client-side, this is not the concern of the server.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I find the term "sanitization" to be misleading. I always say either "escaping" (for correctness and security) or "validation" (for data quality).

Comment: Server-side validation may also be appropriate, depending on how the application is architected.

Comment: @200_success I like to differentiate between data integrity and business validation. Data integrity is done by the RDBM, while business validation is done by your app.

Answer (score 7):

I'll tell you, I definitely had trouble reproducing your expression. The Refiddle you linked to was using JavaScript's regex engine, not [PHP's PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).

Now, what you're doing is something that is complicated. Just so everyone knows, [here is the official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/) regarding fonts of the web.

If we dig a little, we will [find](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-webfonts-20020802/#font-descriptors) a sentence saying:

> Therefore, only the range of ISO 10646 characters will be used to
>   qualify matches for the font face name.

Now, the definition of "ISO 10646" will [give us something like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set):

> The Universal Character Set (UCS), defined by the International
>   Standard ISO/IEC 10646, contains nearly one hundred thousand abstract
>   characters.

From the way I see, your check of `\w` doesn't cover this. The documentation *you* linked to specifically say:

> Some font formats allow fonts to carry multiple localizations of the
>   family name.

And the example directly below that covers the locale of (I'm pretty sure) Japan. The `\w` word check often relies on the user's localization configuration, which is in no way subject to a single standard.

---

I don't know how you're using this information, but if it's to just style a page, let the user enter what they want. The page will break harmlessly and it will be their loss. Styling with a `/*`  or `DROP TABLE` will only make their webpage less stylish! If you're storing this information, same principle goes, just make sure to used prepared statements when inserting into your database.

Comment: I'm using this information to allow a CSS framework to be customized. Their input will be put into an interpreter and processed, possibly stored into a database in the future. I need to give them the freedom to provide legitimate information, to protect myself from malicious text, and to protect them from malformed strings if it is beyond _their_ skill level

Comment: I quoted that documentation because it gives an exact list of characters that are usable in the property. You must find out how to implement this wide character set in your regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Be advised that `/((([\w -]+)|("[\w -]+"))( *, *)?)+/` is greedy and stalls for longer font-family lists. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AuHNtL/1

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend dumping the idea of free form text.  While I don't understand your use-case completely, I suggest giving the user a list to choose from.  Allow the user to pick or sort values from your list.  On the back end, you would only allow values from the sanctioned list and this will ease the coding quite a bit.

Comment: I intend to allow the user to provide any font they might have on their site, so a dropdown won't work. Just like @AlexL's answer, I give this one -1 for not being an improvement of my code, or telling me how to improve it, or that it cannot be improved, instead opting to tell me how to conceptually build a project I have not described.